# What could happen if task stack size exceeded in freeRTOS mode of STM32, C

Tags: stack, freertos, stm32h7, hardfault

I am working with a project where I need to establish Ethernet connection in order to configure MQTT protocol. I am using FreeRTOS tasks and LwIP MQTT library. Although, while the program is running and MQTT subscriptions are appearing to the my screen, after a couple of minutes the screen gets frozen and doesn't response to anything unless I make a reset. I have to mention that I am using a Riverdi screen for my implementation STM32H7 microcontroller which has a default FreeRTOS task with stack size of 512 words (2048 bytes).

If the stack size is exceeded then is it possible to make my screen go to HardFault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's certainly possible. If the stack is too small, either other contents in memory will get overwritten (which would likely result in undefined behavior), or a non-existing memory address could get accessed (which would most likely result in a HardFault).